# How to check if two elements have the same text formats?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, tlf

How do I check if two paragraph elements or two spans have the same formats?

I have two paragraphs and when I export them they have the exact same attributes:

```
<p fontWeight="bold"><span>Hello world</span></p>
<p fontWeight="bold"><span>Hello world</span></p>
```

I can find a way to get the string with regex and do a string compare but I'm sure there was a method like this which seems more robust:

```
paragraph1.formatsMatch(paragraph2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer:

```
var same:Boolean = myParagraph.equalUserStyles(myOtherParagraph);
```

It is always showing true so I have to run some more tests. But I think it only checks users styles and not textlayout format or computed format.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/elements/FlowElement.html

Comment: This only checks the users styles. I'm leaving it as an answer for posterity.